# Changed themes on test environment, cannot access category menu in admin

Tags: admin, catalog

I am seeing the following error:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:89:"Source model "ThemeConfig/catcolumncount" not found for attribute "products_column_count"";i:1;s:4178:"#0 /home/shop_test/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Abstract.php(387): Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', 'Source model "T...')
1 /home/shop_test/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form.php(201): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract->getSource()
2 /home/shop_test/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Tab/Attributes.php(113): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form->_setFieldset(Array, Object(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Fieldset))
3 /home/shop_test/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form.php(144): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tab_Attributes->_prepareForm()
4 /home/shop_test/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(885): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form->_beforeToHtml()
5 /home/shop_test/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Tabs.php(140): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
6 /home/shop_test/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(261): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tabs->_prepareLayout()
7 /home/shop_test/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
8 /home/shop_test/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Edit/Form.php(55): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'tabs')
9 /home/shop_test/htdocs/app/code/local/Amasty/Catcopy/Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Category/Edit/Form.php(11): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Edit_Form->_prepareLayout()
10 /home/shop_test/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(261): Amasty_Catcopy_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Category_Edit_Form->_prepareLayout()
11 /home/shop_test/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
12 /home/shop_test/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form/Container.php(82): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...')
13 /home/shop_test/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(261): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container->_prepareLayout()
14 /home/shop_test/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
15 /home/shop_test/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'category.edit')
16 /home/shop_test/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'category.edit')
17 /home/shop_test/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
18 /home/shop_test/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
19 /home/shop_test/htdocs/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
20 /home/shop_test/htdocs/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(268): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
21 /home/shop_test/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(275): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout(NULL, true, true)
22 /home/shop_test/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/CategoryController.php(201): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->loadLayout()
23 /home/shop_test/htdocs/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(417): Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_CategoryController->editAction()
24 /home/shop_test/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('edit')
25 /home/shop_test/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
26 /home/shop_test/htdocs/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(348): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
27 /home/shop_test/htdocs/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
28 /home/shop_test/htdocs/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
29 {main}";s:3:"url";s:80:"/index.php/vapetron/catalog_category/index/key/050428bee74402554c5ed100a9e7e17f/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

I am guessing some module that has since been eliminated since I changed themes attached an attribute to the catalog in the database. However, I can't figure out which tables to eliminate. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: your theme is not properly install

Answer (score 1):

Either you are missing a file called `[Namespace]/ThemeConfig/Model/Catcolumncount.php` either you removed some extension that added the attribute `products_column_count`.
if it's the second option, look in the table `eav_attribute` for a record with `attribute_code = 'products_column_count'` and delete it.